# why this while loop not running twice as i have used for loop?

Tags: c

samplefile1.txt contains same a name that i want to write twice in a new file.
samplefile1.txt - John
output that i want is as below
samplefile2.txt - JohnJohn

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr1;
    FILE *ptr2;
    ptr1=fopen("samplefile1","r");
    ptr2=fopen("samplefile2.txt","w");  
    char a;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        a=fgetc(ptr1);          
        while(a!=EOF){
            fprintf(ptr2,"%c",a);
            printf("%c",a); 
            a=fgetc(ptr1);  
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr1);
    fclose(ptr2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You read the entire file in the first iteration of the loop (when `i = 0`). So it is exhausted when the 2nd iteration starts (when `i = 1`). You can `rewind` the file to the begining.

Comment: You need `int a;` because `fgetc()` and it's relatives return an `int`, not a `char`.  I'm not sure that's your whole problem, but it is one problem.  A common one. This a might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop, it reads the whole file. so it doesn't enter your second loop at all.

```
   while(a!=EOF){
        fprintf(ptr2,"%c",a);
        printf("%c",a); 
        a=fgetc(ptr1);  
    }
```

you might use the rewind function to sets the file position to the beginning of the file e.g. `rewind(ptr1);`

Answer (score 2):

The second time you run the loop, you're already at the end of the file, so it never enters the body of the `while` loop because the comparison fails.